# How to check multiple extensions of a file in jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo uploader widget in my app. On "select" event I am having to check to see if the file uploaded is not one of the file that we want to allow then stop the user from uploading the file and display an error message. Below code is what I came up with.

```
 function onSelect(e) {
            var notAllowed = false;
            $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
                var ext = value.extension.toLowerCase();
                if (ext !== '.docx' || '.csv'|| '.doc' || '.docm' || '.dotx' || '.dotm' || '.xls' || '.xlt' || '.xltx' || '.xlsm' || '.xlsx' || '.ppt' || '.pptx' || '.pptm' || '.ppsx' || '.potx' || '.ppsm' || '.tiff' || '.tif' || '.txt')
                {
                    that.viewModel.set("documentMessage", "FileType not allowed.");
                    notAllowed = true;
                }
                if (e.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024 > 50) {
                    that.viewModel.set("documentMessage", "Max FileSize of 50MB exceeded.");
                    notAllowed = true;
                }

                console.log("Name: " + value.name);
                console.log("Size: " + value.size + " bytes");
                console.log("Extension: " + value.extension);
            });
            var breakPoint = 0;
            if (notAllowed == true)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            };
```

For some reason it is always displaying error message when user uploads the file regardless if the file is of accepted format. When I check only for one file format then this works flawlessly. Something like this:

```
 function onSelect(e) {
            var notAllowed = false;
            $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
                var ext = value.extension.toLowerCase();
                if (ext !== '.docx')
                {
                    that.viewModel.set("documentMessage", "FileType not allowed.");
                    notAllowed = true;
                }
                if (e.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024 > 50) {
                    that.viewModel.set("documentMessage", "Max FileSize of 50MB exceeded.");
                    notAllowed = true;
                }

                console.log("Name: " + value.name);
                console.log("Size: " + value.size + " bytes");
                console.log("Extension: " + value.extension);
            });
            var breakPoint = 0;
            if (notAllowed == true)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            };
```

I need to be able to check for multiple extensions. What am i doing wrong in the first block of code ?
Thanks!

Comment: just fyi, you'd be better off making the block check server side. JS i easy enough to crack and if someone wants to do some damage, chances are, they are looking for a loophole like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if (ext !== '.docx' || '.csv'|| '.doc' || '.docm' || '.dotx' || '.dotm' || '.xls' || '.xlt' || '.xltx' || '.xlsm' || '.xlsx' || '.ppt' || '.pptx' || '.pptm' || '.ppsx' || '.potx' || '.ppsm' || '.tiff' || '.tif' || '.txt')
```

Is not what you really want. Your first conditions is ok (`ext !== '.docx'`) but the following are just strings which evaluate to `true`, that is why those conditions are always satisfied. Try this in your console `Boolean("false")`. It will evaluate to `true` because of type of the parameter string and not for its content. A string is *true* in javascript. This will produce the same result as your `if`:

```
if ('false') { console.log("I'm truthy") }
if (false) { console.log("I'm truthy") }
```

So make all your conditions like the first one:

```
if (ext !== '.docx' || ext !== '.csv'|| ext !== '.doc' /* and so on */
```

For readability and even performance, you can change you condition to check an array of string, making just one condition instead of all those conditions:

```
var forbiddenExtensions = ['.docx', '.csv', '.doc'];
if (forbiddenExtensions.indexOf(ext) > -1) {
    // Error
}
```

Comment: Even better: `if(['.docx', '.csv', '.doc', '.docm', '.dotx', '.dotm', '.xls'].indexOf(ext) > -1){ blabla }`, possibly saving the array in some configuration place ^^

Comment: thank you so much for the right answer with explanation as well !! :) This worked perfecttt!